# Unity3D - Using different dependencies in different environments

Tags: unity-game-engine

I aum using Unity 2019.3

I have my dependencies defined in my manifest.json like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "com.emt.foo1": "https://github.com/emt/foo1.git",
    "com.emt.foo2": "https://github.com/emt/foo2.git",
    ...
  }
}
```

But when I am developing locally, I would like to use a different version, maybe a local version, like for instance this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "com.emt.foo1": "file:/home/emt/packages/foo1",
    "com.emt.foo2": "https://github.com/emt/foo2.git",
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to define different packages for different environments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define local dependencies. [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-localpath.html) is Unity Documentation about it.

Comment: The question is not how to define local dependencies. If you read my question, you will see that I already know how to do that. The question is about how to set different dependencies, depending on the environment.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Sorry, my bad. Check [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/multiple-package-sources.772961/), hope it helps. :)